# Getting error while adding intellij project to gitlab

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab, push

Did following:

- git init
- git add .
- git commit -m "message"
- git remote add origin [https://gitlab.com/xxxxxx/tmp.git'](https://gitlab.com/xxxxxx/tmp.git%27)
- git push -u origin master

I am getting following error

> error: src refspec master does not match any
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/xxxxxx/tmp.git'

Answer (score 0):

It is probable the remote repository created on GitHub has for main branch the branch `main` (see [GitLab documentation](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/03/10/new-git-default-branch-name/))

- either you push your local master to main:

  ```
    git push -u origin master:main
  ```
- or (better) you rename your local branch as main

  ```
    git branch -m master main
    git push -u origin main
  ```

Comment: @Xutv Did you check the name of the default branch in your repository created on the remote side? What does git status return (it should display the name of your local branch). Is the name of the local branch the same as the one from the remote repository?